# Invoke powershell script from another

Tags: powershell

How can I invoke a powershell script from within another script?
This is not working:

```
$param1 = "C:/Users/My Folder/file1"
$param2 = "C:/Users/My Folder/file2"
$command = "C:/Users/My Folder/second.ps1"

Invoke-expression $command -File1 $param1 -File2 $param2
```

...
Second.ps1:

```
param(
[string]File1, [string]File2)...
```

Comment: `& $command -File1 $param1 -File2 $param2`

Comment: Thank you!!!   It worked

Comment: As a general Powershell tip : use functions instead of seperate script files for these actions : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/26/don-t-write-scripts-write-powershell-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If there are no spaces:

```
Invoke-expression "$command $param1 $param2"
```

If you know where the spaces are:

```
Invoke-expression "$command `$param1HasSpaces` $param2"
```

NB: If your execution policy is restricted (check with `get-executionpolicy` use:

```
Invoke-Expression "powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command `"$command $param1 $param2`""
```

Comment: That gives me: "Invoke-Expression: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts: 'C:/Users/My Folder/second.ps1 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you slightly change your approach. Basically create the command string you want to execute, then create a scriptblock object from that and then use Invoke-Command instead of Invoke-Expression.

```
$param1 = "C:/Users/My Folder/file1"
$param2 = "C:/Users/My Folder/file2"
$command = "C:/Users/My Folder/second.ps1"

$str = '{0} -File1 "{1}" -File2 "{2}"' -f ($command, $param1, $param2)
$sb  =  [scriptblock]::Create($str)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
```